# Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in **/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php after adding new source_model

Tags: magento-1.9

My config.xml:

```
<modules>
    <Cart_ShippingMethod>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Cart_ShippingMethod>
</modules>

<global>


    <models>
        <cart_insurance_upsell>
            <class>Cart_ShippingMethod_Model</class>
        </cart_insurance_upsell>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <cart_insurance_upsell>
            <class>Cart_ShippingMethod_Helper</class>
        </cart_insurance_upsell>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <cart_insurance_upsell>
            <class>Cart_ShippingMethod_Block</class>
        </cart_insurance_upsell>
    </blocks>

    <resources>
        <insurance_upsell_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Cart_ShippingMethod</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </insurance_upsell_setup>
    </resources>

</global>

<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <cart_insurance_upsell>
                <file>cart_insurance_upsell.xml</file>
            </cart_insurance_upsell>
        </updates>
    </layout>

    <routers>
        <cart_insurance_upsell>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Cart_ShippingMethod</module>
                <frontName>insuranceupsell</frontName>
            </args>
        </cart_insurance_upsell>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <insurance>
                <file>insurance.xml</file>
            </insurance>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

And my system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <cart_shipping_mthd>
            <label>Shipping method</label>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        </cart_shipping_mthd>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <cart_insurance_upsells>
            <label>Configuration</label>
            <tab>cart_shipping_mthd</tab>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <shipping_configuration>
                    <label>Shipping configuration</label>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled>
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </enabled>
                    </fields>
                </shipping_configuration>
                <first_method>
                    <label>First method</label>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <enabled>
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </enabled>
                        <discount_rate>
                            <label>Insurance payment method</label>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>cart_insurance_upsell/system_config_source_payment</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </discount_rate>
                    </fields>
                </first_method>
            </groups>
        </cart_insurance_upsells>
    </sections>
</config>
```

And my model src/app/code/local/Cart/InsuranceUpsell/Model/System/Config/Source/Payment.php:

```
<?php

class Cart_ShippingMethod_Model_System_Config_Source_Payment
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Order percentage')),
            array('value' => 0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Fixed amount')),
        );
    }
}
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: can you post the contents of /app/etc/modules/Cart_ShippingMethod.xml ?

In general it's kind of bad practice to have different names for the Namespace and the router of the module.

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis problem solved. I rewrited all name and it started work

Answer (score 1):

Your `config.xml` file is incorrect.
It should have `<config>` opening and closing tag.

Add this code at the beginning of your config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
```

Then add this code at the end of config.xml file:

```
</config>
```

Comment: done, but still error

Comment: Try to clear your cache, especially Configuration cache

Answer (score 1):

Modify Your Model file code like this.

```
<?php

class Cart_InsuranceUpsell_Model_System_Config_Source_Payment
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 1, 'label'=>'Order percentage'),
            array('value' => 0, 'label'=>'Fixed amount'),
        );
    }
}
```

clear cache and then check.

Comment: if answer help you, accept it as solution so it will help other in community.